# Connect to multiple SQL Servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, settings.settings

I am trying to connect to multiple SQL Servers.I have a connection string stored in the applicationSettings of the Web Config file. This connection string is stored as default in the Settings.designer file because of which I am not able to connect to different SQL servers on remote location. Any Suggestion on how should I tackle this issue. 
Note : If I try to comment out the connection string which is in the Web Config applicationSettings section,  web application takes the data from the Settings.designer.cs file. I even tried placing the connection strings inside the connectionStrings section of the web config file . But of no use

Comment: Your question is confusing, however you can have multiple SqlConnection objects, which you specify different connection string for each. You can hardcode this, use the Web.Config SqlConnection, or use custom variables in Web.Config, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Its probably due to the state on my mind right now. For a start is it possible to store multiple connection strings inside the applicationSettings schema/section of the web Config file ?

Answer (score 0):

applicationSettings is usually not the right spot for connection strings.
You should use the connectionStrings section.
Also, you should not supply a default value for applicationSettings that you expect to change in every environment.  This is a sure way to forget to change config and you'll have an environment pointing to the wrong setting.
That said, it sounds like you are changing the wrong config file.  Default is used when they running application cannot find the setting in config.  Because you mentioned web config, I'm guessing this is ASP.NET.  Take a look to see if you have nested folders with additional web.config files.  Also, check to see that you have included the sectionGroup that defines applicationSettings.

Comment: An Example here
A C# code is used to get data from the database.It makes use of the connectionString stored in the applicationSettings of the webConfig file.This data is then displayed on the web browser using HTML ,JQuery and AJAX. Under Ideal conditions, If I comment out the applicationSettings section of the Web Config file, no data should be retrieved and the display should be blank. However when I comment out the applicationSettings section, Its take the database name and the login credentials from the Settings.designer.cs file 
Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: It might be best to post your config.  Probably, you  need to to into the Settings designer and clear the default value.  This makes the default empty and it will remain empty unless you add the value into the config file.

Comment: Clearing the defaultValue in the Settings.desginer means modifying the Settings.Designer file which would throw unexpected results.As I have read it is advisable not to edit/modify the Designer.cs file

Comment: Its like I have the login credentials of a database stored as DefaultValueAttribute in the .Designer.cs file. And I have a diff value in the Web.Config file. Ideally at runtime the WebConfig values would over ride the values in the Designer.cs which is not happening.The application still takes values from the .Designer file and ignores the ones stored in the Web Config

Comment: Don't edit the Designer.cs.  Clear the default from the settings in the VS GUI (double-click settings or right click the project and go to properties).  That will regenerate the Designer.cs without a default.

Comment: I tried that option. Didnt work. Is it that if I edit the Settings.Settings for example adding another database login credentials, it should be updated in the Settings.Designer file as well

Comment: I'm sorry, but "didnt work" doesn't help. You couldn't open the GUI? You couldn't clear the default value? You opened the GUI, cleared the default value for your connection string property, but the default stayed in Settings.Designer.cs?  Would it help if I explained the way that application settings work?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that comment. When I tried to implement the method U suggested, the default value did not change,It stayed in the Settings.Designer.cs file.After that I tried a couple of things 
1) Removed couple of settings from the Settings.Settings file and followed the same procedure .It still showed the same default settings. I am using VS2008 . Is this a case of corrupted Settings.Designer file ?
2) I tried to exclude the settings.designer file but the application was still working.
I am running out of options here 
Apologize for the previous comment again

Comment: I'm sorry, but it sounds like you need someone to look over your shoulder to see what is wrong.  The only thing I can think to try without seeing exactly what is happening, is wipe out your settings for that project and start over.  Maybe one of the things you've tried to do has gotten the settings into an invalid state and it's not handling your changes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings designer, select the setting for the connection string. Then in the properties pane set the value for 'GenerateDefaultValueInCode' to False. This will cause the application to always fetch the value from the *.config file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From what I have read about the settings.designer file, It is not advisable to edit or modify the designer.cs file .. Correct me if I am wrong. If I try the method mentioned above, would the code be regenerated ?

Comment: You do not need to edit the file. Just select the setting in the designer and take a look at the properties pane. There you will find the property that I mentioned. The files will be regenerated without default values.

Comment: I tried to change the GenerateDefaultValueInCode to False. No change. Is there any way to change the DefaultSettingValueAttribute of the Designer.cs file